# $f(z)=\frac{z}{1+|z|} $ Is 1-1?

Tags: complex-analysis, analysis, functions

So i have to prove if $f(z_1)=f(z_2)$ then $z_1=z_2$ .

I tried substituting $z=x+yi$ i also tried proving their differences in absolute value are zero.None of this work .Im sure im missing a property or something that will make this very easy. I also tried making the first part of the eq belonging is $R$  so the  second part of the eq must have imaginary part  zero. I just dont get to the result i want.

Comment: $g(w) = \frac{w}{1 - \lvert w\rvert}$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Suppose

$$
\frac{z_{1}}{1+|z_{1}|}=\frac{z_{2}}{1+|z_{2}|}.
$$

Then, 
$$
\frac{|z_{1}|}{1+|z_{1}|}=\frac{|z_{2}|}{1+|z_{2}|}
$$
and, hence,
$$
|z_{1}|(1+|z_{2}|)=|z_{2}|(1+|z_{1}|)\implies|z_{1}|=|z_{2}|.
$$

Thus, from the first equation above, we have $z_{1}=z_{2}$. Thus, $f$ is injective.