# Prove this function is injective

Tags: calculus, complex-analysis, functions

Suppose $f:\mathbb{C}\to \mathbb{C}$ be a function defined by $f(z)=\frac{z}{1+|z|}$.Show that $f$ is one-one.

How can I show this?From normal straight forward definition it became very complex.There is also no concept about monotonicity in $\mathbb{C}$.So,what is the procedure?

Comment: Just use definition: start from $f(z_1) = f(z_2)$, then try to conclude $z_1 = z_2$. As an intermediate step, derive $|z_1| = |z_2|$ first from $|f(z_1)| = |f(z_2)|$.

Comment: $f$ fixes the angle of $z$, so it suffices to show that $|f(z_1)| = |f(z_2)| \implies |z_1| = |z_2|$ which follows from a direct computation.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [$f(z)=\frac{z}{1+|z|} $ Is 1-1?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2517326/fz-fracz1z-is-1-1) – found with [Approach0](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=%24f(z)%3D%5Cfrac%7Bz%7D%7B1%2B%7Cz%7C%7D%24)

Answer (score 4):

Say $f(z)= f(w)$ then $|f(z)|=|f(w)|$ so $|z|=|w|=:m$.

Now going back from $f(z)=f(w)$ we get $${z\over 1+m}={w\over 1+m}\implies z=w$$